# Adding to a string in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a string and I want to add one to it rather then it adding a 1 to the end of the string:

Ex. 2 when I add the one it comes out 21 instead I want it to say 3.

Here is the jquery code I am using:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
      showOn: 'focus',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {

        var value1 = '1';
            $('#CIY').val(dateText.split('/')[2]);
            $('#CIM').val(dateText.split('/')[0]);
            $('#CID').val(dateText.split('/')[1]);
            $('#COY').val(dateText.split('/')[2]);
            $('#COM').val(dateText.split('/')[0]);
            $('#COD').val(dateText.split('/')[1]);
        },
          onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            // Parse the selected date
            var instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );

            // Add one day
            date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);

            // Set the new date
            $("#datepicker2").datepicker('setDate', date);  

            $("#datepicker2").datepicker();              
        }

      });
      $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
        showOn: 'focus',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            $('#COY').val(dateText.split('/')[2]);
            $('#COM').val(dateText.split('/')[0]);
            $('#COD').val(dateText.split('/')[1]);
        }
    });

      $("#datepicker1").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
  });
```

It's the first #COD id that I want to convert to a integer then add one.

Here is the part of the form that the jquery is interacting with:

`

Arrive

Depart

```
<input type="text" id="COD" value="" name="COD" />
```

`

Comment: [It's a good thing you're using jQuery for this](http://s.mlkshk.com/r/KC58).

Comment: form `dateText` coming

Answer (score 1):

use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`, e.g.

```
var x = "1";
var y = parseInt(x, 10) + 1;
console.log(y)  // --> 2
```

Comment: Would I replace x with: $('#COD').val(dateText.split('/')[1]);

Comment: I can't tell. Your snippet doesn't really make sense

Comment: parseInt($('#COD').val(dateText.split('/')[1])) + 1; That is what I have and It shoul work I replaced X with $('#COD').val(dateText.split('/')[1], which is the value of that ID. But it only spits out the orignial value not adding one

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = '2';
```

You can use `num = parseInt(num, 10);` to tell javascript to parse as a decimal.

Then you can apply any mathematical operation on it.

Rules for `parseInt(string, radix)`

If the radix parameter is omitted, JavaScript assumes the following:

- If the string begins with `"0x"`, the radix is `16 (hexadecimal)`
- If the string begins with `"0"`, the radix is `8 (octal)`. This feature is deprecated
- If the string begins with any other value, the radix is `10 (decimal)`

Working Code:

```
 <html>
    <head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    var num = $('#cod').val();
    //do something with num
    var str = num.split('/')[1];
     var final = parseInt(str,10)+1; 
    alert(final); //give you 23
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input value="10/22/2013" id="cod">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Here is what I have: var num = '2'; parseInt($('#COD').val(dateText.split('/')[1]), 10) + 1; That doesn't add one it just spits out the original number

Comment: you are setting value to $('#COD') or getting values; `parseInt($('#COD').val(dateText.split('/')[1]), 10) + 1;` is looking will give you nothing

Comment: Im setting a value to #COD, with that code it gives me the second value of the input datepicker1, EX. 10/22/13, so It gives me 22

Comment: Here is a link to the page: http://03698f5.netsolhost.com/this/ when you click on one of the input fields it will give you a calender then the chose of the arrive sets both the select fields, COD is the text field next to the second October select field

Comment: That helps, but now how to I attach it to a input?